# Sorting rows by rows in another table to populate a "What's Hot" list

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have two tables, created thus (only pertinent info shown)

```
CREATE TABLE levels
(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    gameid INT(6),
    created DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,gameid)
)

CREATE TABLE votes
(
    levelid INT(6) NOT NULL REFERENCES levels(id),
    vote TINYINT(1),
    date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(levelid)
)
```

Users get to vote on levels (either +1 or -1) and thus creating a votes record that points back to a level.

What I want to do with the data is this, in non-syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM levels ORDER BY
(select sum(vote) from votes where votes.levelid=levels.id and date is within the last week)
```

How could I turn that into a legitimate mySQL query?  Everything I try gives me an extraordinarily cryptic error message ("Something's wrong!  Check the manual!") and I'm only an advanced beginner at mySQL.

The goal is to return all my levels, sorted by whoever has the best votes sum in the last week... that way new levels will make their way on and older ones will fall off.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

So here's an example of expected results:
Here's my data (rendered in English for clarity):

Levels:
LEVEL1 (id=1)
LEVEL2 (id=2)

votes:
+1 for LEVEL1 two days ago
+1 for LEVEL1 ten days ago
+1 for LEVEL1 twenty days ago
+1 for LEVEL2 one day ago
+1 for LEVEL2 three days ago
-1 for LEVEL2 thirty days ago

So I can do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LEVELS ORDER BY (select sum(vote) from votes where levelid=levels.id)
```

and that gets me +3 for LEVEL1, and +1 for LEVEL2.

BUT, in the last seven days, I should see +1 for LEVEL1, and +2 for LEVEL2, thus returning LEVEL2 first.

Also, I get the general idea that "order by (select..." would be pretty slow.

One more edit:

This query works:

```
SELECT * FROM levels ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE levelid=levels.id AND votes.date>=( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY )) DESC
```

...but is that the best way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: I would suggest adding some sample data (enough to illustrate the intent) and the expected result. (Use [edit].)

Comment: Okay, I will edit the question.  I tried to put the data here, but formatting makes it unreadable.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I think you need to create a different primary key for votes here; as is, each level can only have 1 vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a left join:

```
SELECT levels.*, coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) as total_vote
FROM levels 
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.levelid = levels.id
WHERE votes.date >=( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY ))
GROUP BY levels.id
ORDER BY coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) desc;
```

The coalesces here ensure that levels that haven't been voted on get a score (instead of null) and are sorted correctly.

Comment: Andrew, is this a faster method than the order by (select) that I put up above?  This query will probably get hit pretty often.

Comment: Yes, SQL engines are optimized to perform joins like this. The SQL engine can perform all of the work of a join in one "step." Your query, where you order by a sub-SELECT, isn't terribly performant, because it contains what is called a "correlated sub-query"; that is, the SQL engine needs to perform an additional SELECT for each row returned by the primary SELECT.

Comment: Andrew, I am trying to convert my code over to this join version, and I am suffering a few syntax issues.

I send this:

 SELECT coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) as total_vote, levels.id,levels.name,levels.rating,levels.updated,users.username,users.countrycode,levels.playcount,levels.wincount,comments FROM levels,users WHERE gameid=1 AND users.id=levels.authorid LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.levelid=levels.id WHERE votes.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY )) GROUP BY levels.id ORDER BY coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) DESC LIMIT 0,10

and I'm getting an error 'near LEFT JOIN...'

I assume it's the "where?"

Comment: The select syntax is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - it basically means that you only get one WHERE clause, and it should come after all of the joins, and before the group by. It is okay for the where clause to refer to rows from multiple tables.