# Fixing syntax on complex query with join (advanced beginner needs help)

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to put together a fairly complex multi-table query.  I have a non-join working query, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT levels.*,users.username,users.countrycode, 
   FROM levels,users WHERE gameid=$gameid AND users.id=levels.authorid
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE levelid=levels.id AND
   votes.date>=(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY)) DESC, levels.created DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

I was advised [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362244/sorting-rows-by-rows-in-another-table-to-populate-a-whats-hot-list) that doing a table join would be a better solution.  So I put together this query (with help from Andrew Rueckert):

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) as total_vote, 
levels.*, users.username,users.countrycode, 
   FROM levels,users WHERE gameid=1 AND users.id=levels.authorid 
   LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.levelid=levels.id 
      WHERE votes.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY )) GROUP BY levels.id ORDER BY 
      coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) DESC 
         LIMIT 0,10
```

First off, this second query just syntax errors out... I suspect it is the where clause on the third line, but I can't seem to find a good answer on how to organize this correctly.  Can anyone advise me to the correct syntax?

Second, I want this query to skip any row from "levels" that does not have  SUM(vote)>0 in table "votes"... but I can't turn that into working SQL.  Anything I try, it gives me a generic "you blew it" error.  Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the rewritten query, i think it is a syntax issue

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) as total_vote, 
levels.*, users.username,users.countrycode, 
 FROM level LEFT OUTER JOIN users on users.id=levels.authorid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.levelid=levels.id 
  WHERE votes.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY )) and gameid=1 
   GROUP BY levels.id   ORDER BY  coalesce(sum(votes.vote),0) DESC 
     LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: When I use this, I get incorrect results-- the whole left outer join deal is difficult for me to debug because I can't comprehend the logic there.  But when I run that query, I get different results than my order by (select) query.